# SQL INSERT SELECT from Table2 to Table3

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert ID from Table1 and Table2 into Table3.My table design is:

```
Table1:
Id_Table1
field1 etc.

Table2:
Id_Table2
field1 etc.

Table3:
Id_Table3
Id_Table1_FK
Id_Table2_FK
```

I do this when I save records for Table1. Meanwhile I have Datagridview in my form, which uses comboboxcell to view records from Table2. When I select some record from Table2, both ID's (Table1 & Table2) needs to be inserted into Table3.

Here is my code so far (obviously wrong):

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Id_Table3, Id_Table1, Id_Table2) 

SELECT Id_Table2 FROM Table2 WHERE serial_no=" & MyDGV.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

VALUES (Id_Table3_seq.nextval, Id_Table1_seq.currval,????)
```

So, my problem stucks with Id_Table2 which needs to be selected first by Datagridview.Row cell value, and then result passed like a parameter to Table3. Any suggestions ? Probably an easy one, I just don't know how to start...

Comment: My question may be stupid but can you be sure that your select query would return exactly 1 value? may it return no value?

Comment: @romulus001, no It can't return no value. This INSERT occurs only If you select some record from Comboboxcell in Datagrid.

Comment: @romulus001, regarding that, I already added Top 1 to the query to make sure that it will only return one recordset. But is optional if the field is unique. (as I've mentioned in my edit).

Comment: @Crush Sundae : I preferred to ask that as I'm currently migrating microsoft access datatables to microsoft sql server, I made a similar query as your initial one but I failed at running it, adding `TOP 1` in my select queries solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your point right, this is what you need maybe?

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Id_Table3, Id_Table1, Id_Table2) 
VALUES (Id_Table3_seq.nextval, Id_Table1_seq.currval,(
SELECT Top 1 Id_Table2 FROM Table2 WHERE serial_no='" & MyDGV.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'
))
```

Edited: Added `Top 1` to make sure the subquery will only return 1 recordset. It's optional if the field you are selecting is unique.

Comment: thanks, you understood me ! I didn't knew I could write SQL like this too.

Comment: Please use SQL parameters instead of a string.

Comment: @AlexB., how ? Any why, is It better ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82, one of its use is to avoid [SQL Injections](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/).

Comment: @AlexB,@Crush Sundae - If you meant like this I allready have it - cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Id_Table2", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)). But then I will use this parameter as code provided

Comment: `TOP 1` is invalid for Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks. I used It without anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SELECT` that returns constant valus:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Id_Table3, Id_Table1, Id_Table2) 
select Id_Table3_seq.nextval, 
       Id_Table1_seq.currval,
       Id_Table2
FROM Table2 
WHERE serial_no='" & MyDGV.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "';
```

---

<sup>In general you should not concatenate values into a SQL string. Use a prepared statement with parameters (placeholders) instead (don't know how that is done in VB.net)</sup>